# EF Core transaction behavior

Tags: .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, transactions

Does anyone know if EF Core rolls back transaction automatically if a `DbUpdateException` happens? I am using a Mysql query which use `FOR UPDATE` clause. I want to know if I have to rollback the transaction when a `DbUpdateException` happens? Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined your own transaction scope and then passed it to a db context then yes you need to handle it your self, as far as i know.
So try/catch when defining a `using(var transScope = new TransactionScope())`, but if you just have an instance of dbCtx, do some changes and just call Save, it will not persist anything if anything is thrown on that particular saveChanges call, as if it has its own transactionScope ( which it does )